# How to get the average temperature for N days prior to a specific date in R, accounting for differences in station data?

Tags: r

This question is part of a previous one that I had ([How to get the average temperature for N days prior to a specific date in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70964153/how-to-get-the-average-temperature-for-n-days-prior-to-a-specific-date-in-r/70964322?noredirect=1#comment125549323_70964322)), however things have complicated a bit (at least for me).

I have two datasets: one dataset (A) has the temperatures for each day, and on the other dataset (B) I have the individuals id and the date of birth (dob). I need to get the average temperature for the last 3 days prior to the dob of each individual. For example: if individual 1 was born in 02/20/2021, I need the average temperature from 02/17/2021 to 02/19/2021. However, I also have data coming from different weather station id (in df A), that needs to correspond with the right farm (in df B).
Is there a way I could do that in R, so my output would be ind | dob | avg_temp, accounting for the right weather station. Here is one example data (in my real case, my data has a very large number of days, individuals, farms and station):

```
temp <- c(26,27,28,30,32,27,28,29)
date <- as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-16-2021', '02-17-2021', '02-18-2021', '02-19-2021', '02-20-2021', '02-21-2021',
                  '02-22-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y")
station <- c('A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'A1')
A <- data.frame(date, temp, station)
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
dob <- as.Date(c('02-18-2021', '02-17-2021', '02-20-2021', '02-23-2021', '02-25-2021', '02-23-2021', '02-17-2021',
                 '02-25-2021', '02-25-2021', '02-23-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y")
farm <- c('A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2')
B <- data.frame(id, dob, farm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification. This extension of the function includes the location to calculate the average temperature. This assumes `farm` and `station` have corresponding values despite having different column names, as in your example. I've used `mapply` here to make sure the elements line up (i.e. x[1] goes with location[1], x[2] with location[2] and so on). That way if a particular date of birth only happens in one location it won't be calculated for all locations. I believe you could use `lapply` as well.

```r
library(lubridate)

myfunc <- function(x, location){
  three_days <- as.Date(x - ddays(3))
  
  A <- A[A$date < x & A$date >= three_days & A$station %in% location, ]
  avg_temp <- mean(A$temp)
  dat <- data.frame(dob = x, avg_temp = avg_temp, farm = location)
  return(dat)
}

dobs <- unique(B[,c("dob", "farm")])

avg_temps <- mapply(myfunc, x = dobs$dob, location = dobs$farm, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
avg_temps <- do.call(rbind, avg_temps)

B <- merge(B, avg_temps, by = c("dob", "farm"))

B
#>           dob farm id avg_temp
#> 1  2021-02-17   A2  2       27
#> 2  2021-02-17   A2  7       27
#> 3  2021-02-18   A1  1       27
#> 4  2021-02-20   A1  3       28
#> 5  2021-02-23   A1  4       28
#> 6  2021-02-23   A2  6       28
#> 7  2021-02-23   A2 10       28
#> 8  2021-02-25   A1  5       29
#> 9  2021-02-25   A1  8       29
#> 10 2021-02-25   A1  9       29
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>